# variables' scope and place the following code inside one of the functions in scope.js so the output is a: 1, b: 8, c: 6

Tags: javascript

```
 var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;  

 (function firstFunction(){  
     var b = 5, c = 6;  

     (function secondFunction(){  
         var b = 8;  

         (function thirdFunction(){  
             var a = 7, c = 9;  

             (function fourthFunction(){  
                 var a = 1, c = 8;  

             })();  
         })();  
     })();  
 })();
```

Use your knowledge of the variables' scope and place the following code
  inside one of the functions in scope.js so the output is a: 1, b: 8, c: 6

```
 console.log("a: "+a+", b: "+b+", c: "+c);
```

Comment: Im missing the question

Comment: where can I put the console.log(); to be able to have the same result which they are asking to me?thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to get good responses. This looks like a student programmiing exercise that you have just tried to get us to do for you - SO doesn't work like that. You need to show that you have made some effort to solve it yourself, and show where you think the problem is

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

(function firstFunction(){
 var b = 5, c = 6;  
 (function secondFunction(){  
     var b = 8;  
     console.log("a: "+a+", b: "+b+", c: "+c); //a: 1, b: 8, c: 6
     (function thirdFunction(){  
         var a = 7, c = 9;  

         (function fourthFunction(){  
             var a = 1, c = 8;  

         })();  
     })();  
 })();  
})();
```

Comment: I did the same but was not running ,thanks a lot.i guess I had a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3; 
(function firstFunction(){  
         var b = 5, c = 6;  

         (function secondFunction(){  
             var b = 8;  

             (function thirdFunction(){  
                 var a = 7, c = 9;  

                 (function fourthFunction(){  
                     var a = 1, c = 8;  

                 })();  
             })(); 
    console.log("a: "+a+", b: "+b+", c: "+c);  // it's here because of 'hoisting'. if you need more I can explain
         })();  
     })();
```

Comment: Nothing to do with "hoisting". The variable declarations and initialisers are the first statement in each function, there is nowhere to "hoist" them to. Anyway, assignment is done *after* declarations, it relates to availability of variables, not their values.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I agree with incorrect usage of that definition.